# How can we use escape in dynamically added fields of Kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a field in kendo grid like shown in the below code.Data dynamically append using AJAX call in MVC.

```
    {
      field: "",
      title: "Name",
      template:"<input type='button' value='Name'/>"
      width: 100
     },
```

But When the name contains **'** or **"** symbol, the display name showing till that symbol only.

For example if the name is `Kevin's doe` ,in the view am getting only the name `Kevin` only .How can i escape from this?Is there any way to do this?
I need to get the attributes into a jquery function,there also am getting half of the name only

Comment: First of all, you are missing the '=' after value, and the end of template is wrong (the " should be at the end) with also a ','

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
{
  field: "",
  title: "Name",
  template:"<input type='button' value=\"Name\" />",
  width: 100
 },
```